# slick.js hide slideshow until click element on screen

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using slick.js (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

What I want to do is hide a slideshow until the user clicks an element on the page. The problem is, when the slideshow fades in, all I see is the next and prev buttons, no images.

css:

```
#slideshow2 {
  width: 840px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: none;
}
```

jquery:

```
    $('#slideshow2').slick({
            accessibility: true,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            arrows: true,
            variableWidth: true,
            prevArrow: "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-o-left'></i>",
            nextArrow: "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-o-right'></i>"
        });

   $('#edgar_head').on('click', function() {
            $('#slideshow2').fadeIn();

        });
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: can you wrap slideshow in a div and show/hide that div? or you may call slick plugin on fadeIn function callback.

Comment: @HADI: showing/hiding a wrapper doesn't accomplish what I want. I'm able to hide the slideshow just as it is. If I call the slick plugin on fadeIn, then the slideshow images appear on my page as just images, not in a slideshow.

Comment: can you please put your code is jsfiddle?

Comment: http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/kaufmann/test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had to do:
css:

```
#slideshow2 {
    width: 840px;
    margin: 20px auto; 
    opacity: 0; /* so I can fade it in once display is set to block*/
    display:none;
}
```

jquery:

```
 $('#slideshow2').slick({ //initialize, so the slideshow is properly styled //onload
            accessibility: true,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            arrows: true,
            variableWidth: true,
            prevArrow: "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-o-left'></i>",
            nextArrow: "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-o-right'></i>"
        });

        $('#edgar_head').on('click', function() {
            //alert();
            $('#slideshow2').slick('unslick'); //unslick it
             $('#slideshow2').css('display','block'); //change display none to //display block
             $('#slideshow2').slick({ //reinitialize
                accessibility: true,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                arrows: true,
                prevArrow: "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-o-left'></i>",
                nextArrow: "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-o-right'></i>"
                });
            $("#slideshow2").delay( 100 ).animate({"opacity":"1"},1000  ); //fade in by animating opacity

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything in CSS. Just `display:none` in `#slideshow2` as you already have.

And add this code -

```
var sliderAdded = false;
$('#edgar_head').click(function(event) {
    // prevent multiple slick calling 
    if(sliderAdded === true) {
        return false;
    }

    $('#slideshow2').stop().fadeIn(function(){
        $(this).slick({
            accessibility: true,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            arrows: true,
            prevArrow: "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-o-left'></i>",
            nextArrow: "<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-o-right'></i>"
        });

        sliderAdded = true;
    });
});
```

When you were calling slick on document ready then slick started bind its event and slick found that your element's height is 0 because it's display none. You need to call slick after document appears with proper height. I hope this gives you hint why it wasn't working.